# Linking button to controller using jquery and ajax (url)

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, linkbutton

I'm trying to create a button that does a database lookup for a value in an MVC project. I'm a bit stuck after reading round so could do with some tips.

Actual cshmtl for Create

```
  odel OncologyRTA.Controllers.oncologyPatient

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Add new patient</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <button type="button" name="button" value="find">Search</button>


    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4><font color="red"><strong>LIVE Dataset</strong></font></h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HospitalID, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.HospitalID, new { onkeyup = "InputToUpper(this);"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HospitalID)
            </dd>

            <dt>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NHS_No_, "NHS No.", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NHS_No_)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NHS_No_)
            </dd>

            <dt>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Forename, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Forename, new { onkeyup = "InputToUpper(this);", Name="Forename"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Forename)
            </dd>

            <dt>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Surname, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Surname, new { onkeyup = "InputToUpper(this);" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Surname)
            </dd>

            <dt>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DOB, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DOB, new { @Value = "dd/MM/yyyy" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DOB)
            </dd>

            <dt>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Active, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Active)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Active)
            </dd>

            <dt>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Deceased, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Deceased)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Deceased)
            </dd>

        </dl>



        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}


<script>
    function InputToUpper(obj) {
        if (obj.value != "") {
            obj.value = obj.value.toUpperCase();
        }
    }
</script>

<script>
    $("button[name='button']").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var uquery = $('#HospitalID').val();
        var url = '@Url.Action("GetData")';
        var data = { value: uquery }
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#Forename').val(data.HospitalID);
            }
        });
    })
</script>



<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Actual code for class

```
>  public class Lkup
>     {
>         public string HospitalID { get; set; }
>         public string NHS_No_ { get; set; }
>         public string Forename { get; set; }
>         public string Surname { get; set; }
>         public System.DateTime DOB { get; set; }
>     }
```

HttpGet code in controller

```
[HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetData(string value)
        {
            var result = new Lkup();

            string connect = "Server=server\\instance;Database=SQLtable;Trusted_Connection=True";
            string query = "select * from table1 where pkey =" +value;

            using (SqlConnection sql1 = new SqlConnection(connect))
            {
            sql1.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            {       if (rdr != null)
                    {
                        while (rdr.Read())
                        {
                            result.HospitalID = "column1";
                            result.Forename = "column2";
                            result.Surname = "colum3";
                        }
                    }
            rdr.Close();
            }
            sql1.Close();
            }

            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

***** UPDATE *****

I think the code is now fine, we've tested some javascript alerts and they are pulling the correct field and data. The problem seems to be in the ajax call as it gets a 404 when trying to route through to the controller. Like this:

```
GET http://localhost:59845/oncologyPatientsController/GetData?id=1234567 404 (Not Found)
send @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:23
x.extend.ajax @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:23
(anonymous function) @ Create:157
x.event.dispatch @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:22
v.handle @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:22
```

Comment: The line `string query = "SELECT val.1, val.2, val.3, val.4 FROM [SQL1\\INSTANCE].dB.dbo.tbl1 AS L INNER JOIN [SQL1\\INSTANCE].dB.dbo.SID AS S ON 1.ui = 2.ui WHERE val.1 = " +value;` is ripe for SQL Injection, a serious security issue. See http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/05/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-1.html as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just trying to get the functionality there first then will harden as necessary.

Comment: What is not working? And why are you adding `new { Name="HospitalID" }` etc? - the value of the `name` attribute is already `HospitalID`. And `$('Forename').val(data.HospitalID);` wont do anything - it would need to be `$('#Forename').val(data.HospitalID);`

Comment: Sorry, I must have copied some of the code when I was trying different things to get it to recognise the variables. Have posted the cshtml again, minus the 'Name' attribute added and with the '#' prefixes. Button highlights when depressed but nothing happens after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I usually do is the following to get the ActionMethods URL in the JS code:

```
<button type="button" value="find">Find</button>
<script>
    $("button").click(function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        var uquery = $('HID').val();
        var url = '@Url.Action("GetData","ControllerName")';
        var data = { value: uquery }
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: data,
            success : function(data) 
            {
                $('HID').val(data.Value1);
            }
        });})
```

But as Hackerman mentioned, if your view belongs to that controller you can just do:

```
@Url.Action("GetData")
```

Comment: Accepted this as the answer as it contained the specific line in the example and was submitted first if I'm reading correctly. The further problems I encountered were because I was appending Controller to the controller name: var url = '@Url.Action("GetData","ControllerName")';

Answer (score 0):

If your view belong to the same controller you just need to change you code a little bit:

```
var url = 'GetData';
```

If you view is in another controller, then this should works:

```
var url = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/YouControllerName/GetData")%>';
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use your Controller class name in place of YourControllerName, GetData is the action name, in your case.

```
@Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName")
```

returns the action url.

```
e.g:   
var url = '@Url.Action("GetData", "YourControllerName")';
```

Try this:

```
    <script>
>     $("button[name='button']").click(function (event) {
>         event.preventDefault();
>         var uquery = $('#HospitalID').val();
>         var url = '@Url.Action("GetData")';
>         var data = { value: uquery }
>         $.ajax({
>             url: url,
>             data: data,
>             success: function (result) {
>                 $('#Forename').val(result.hid);
>             }
>         });
>     }) </script>
```

Comment: Tried a few and all seem to validate but it doesn't seem to fire anything. I don't get any feedback from the button is pressed but nothing happens. Gonna have a mess with fiddler etc.

Comment: $('HID').val(data.Value1); is not valid code. There is no Value1 propery in the returned data. If you have a HTML element with id 'HID', you should use $('#HID').val(data.Hid );

Comment: Sorry, not able to access your link at work. Can you put the cshtml code as a part of the question, just like you have shared the controller and the javascript code?

Comment: Added to OP - thanks. I've still not posted full contents of the controller with SQL query as it has obviously SQL server names and database details.

Comment: Updated OP with all code and removed pseudocode (except database details). Still no joy, the button doesn't seem to fire anything. I get no feedback, prompts, errors etc. Thank for the ongoing support.

Comment: Why is the answer downvoted? it basically is the same as the one upvoted.